# $state.go no staying in new state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following state declaration

```
$stateProvider.state('csh', {
    url: "/csh",
    views: {
        info: {
            templateUrl: 'partials/csh.template.html',
            controller: 'cshController',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        }
    },
    onEnter: function () {
        console.log('csh enter');
    },
    onExit: function () {
        console.log('csh exit');
    }
});
```

when i call `$state.go('csh')` i see "csh enter" in the console immediately followed by "csh exit" and it goes back to the original state

EDIT: it turns out the `$state.go` is throwing a "Error: transition superseded" though I can't find any docs as to what this means

can anyone tell me whats going on please? I'm completely baffled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it, i had a ui-sref in the parent element of the button, so effectively calling 2 states at the same time - school boy!